# Using a variable as @Subject with sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I got the following Code which runs more or less smoothly.

```
DECLARE @MyId char(4),@MyResult varchar(max), @MySubject varchar(max);
    SET @ID = 5;
    SET @MyId = @ID;

SELECT  @MyResult = SQL_Script FROM Table1 WHERE ID = + @MyId;
SELECT  @MySubject = Subject FROM Table1 WHERE ID = + @MyId;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name='Operator',
  @recipients= 'test@mail.com',  
  @subject= @MySubject,
  @query_result_separator = '   ',
  @query_result_no_padding= 1,
  @body= 'test',
  @query_attachment_filename = 'Test.csv',
  @query= @MyResult , 
  @mailitem_id='1',
  @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 
END
```

The result of the Query which is store in `@MyResult` works just fine, but when I store a String in `@MySubject` I won't get a Mail.

If I write:

```
@subject= @MySubject, <-- Doesn't work (The String is not 'NULL')  
@subject = 'test',    <-- works
```

I have to save a String, which is located in `Table1`, into `@MySubject` and then use it as Subject for my Mail.

Sadly it has to be dynamic so I somehow have to get this to work.

Comment: Have you checked the log in the `msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log` table?

Comment: Just looked into it. It says that the mailserver cant handle the format which is used for the subject. But I don't know why the format is wrong. It is text only (only non text is a space and the ' ' that marks it as a string). Furthermore I tried without the ' ' and it dosn't work either.

Comment: Can you share the full description of the error message in the log?

Comment: The error massage in the log is in german. Dont know if you can use that? I can translate it as good as I can and send it then maybe?

Comment: Oh, If possible can you share the exact content in the `@MySubject` variable? Because if it contains any junk or non-ascii characters it may cause some problem.

Comment: ->  'Test autosendmail' <- is written in it.(Without the arrows)
The ' ' are in it too. There are 21 possible subjects, but I test with the one I stated in this comment. I tried it without the ' ' but that won't work.

Comment: After 2 days of trying and testing I got it working. It seems like there was a control character which looked like a space. Because of that it didn't work, but I had to change the datatype to    nvarchar(255) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using variable is not the issue.

Probably, this

```
@MySubject varchar(max)
```

the @subject parameter supposed to be nvarchar(255)

what is the value of @MySubject ? is it readable text ?

Comment: @MySubject is for example something like this: 'This is a Test-Mail' with the ' '

Comment: I just changed the "varchar(max)" to "nvarchar(255)". But I still won't get a Mail. The Job says it finished without error but I won't get a Mail.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces seem to be the problem:

SET @Subj = 'Test Subject'  <- does not work
SET @Subj = 'Test_Subject'  <- works

Comment: Where is there such a space in the Question?